# Comparing with null by converting value to a constant with isnull

Tags: sql-server, null, isnull

One of our programmers tends to use isnull in MS SQL to compare with NULLs.
That is instead of writing `Where ColumnName Is Null` he writes `Where IsNull(ColumnName,0)=0`

I think that the optimizer will convert the latter into the former anyway, but if it does not - is there a way to prove that the latter is less effective, since it 
1.Compares with null, 
2.Converts to integer, 
3.Compares 2 integers
instead of just comparing with null.

Both ways are really fast for me to be able to use the execution plans (and also I think, that the optimizer plays its part). Is there a way to prove him that just comparing with Null without IsNull is more effective (unless it's not).

Comment: The obvious thing is, they do different things if `0` is a valid value for that column. But, at the end of the day, if this area is where you have a performance bottleneck, congratulations - if it's not, I wouldn't sweat it.

Comment: I'm sorry. Assuming `0` is not valid for the column and all values are greater than zero, but `NULL` is valid. I mean, we're looking at the situation when both conditions are equal in that particular case.

Comment: But it is a reason why "I think that the optimizer will convert the latter into the former anyway" isn't true.

Comment: It's slower and less readable. Of those two, the less readable part would be my peeve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another obvious issue is the `ISNULL` precludes the use of indexes.

Run this setup:

```
create table T1 (
    ID int not null primary key,
    Column1 int null
)
go
create index IX_T1 on T1(Column1)
go
declare @i int
set @i = 10000
while @i > 0
begin
    insert into T1 (ID,Column1) values (@i,CASE WHEN @i%1000=0 THEN NULL ELSE @i%1000 END)
    set @i = @i - 1
end
go
```

Then turn on execution plans and run the following:

```
select * from T1 where Column1 is null
select * from T1 where ISNULL(Column1,0)=0
```

The first uses an index *seek* (using `IX_T1`) and is quite efficient. The second uses an index *scan* on the clustered index - it has to look at *every* row in the table.

On my machine, the second query took 90% of the time, the first 10%.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - I was fairly certain it wasn't SARGable, but I wasn't happy with the pages I was finding in my searches (they were all kind of vague, or mentioned `ISNULL` and SARGable on the same page but in unrelated ways)

Comment: That would be a great example, thank you! 'cause I only managed 50%-50% on non-indexed fields with table scans.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Are there situations where using a function in the where clause **is** SARGable?

Answer (score 0):

IsNull is not well used if you are using it in the where clause and comparing it to 0, the use of isnull is to replace the value null

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

For example:

```
SELECT Description, DiscountPct, MinQty, ISNULL(MaxQty, 0.00) AS 'Max Quantity'
FROM Sales.SpecialOffer;
```

Comment: Well, yes that's the point. Plus extra code makes reading more complex. Though if they are the same effective and both return correct results, the guy looks quite headstrong. He's my boss actually :-)

Comment: Besides, you have the sargable thing, it is not sargable at all, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable, in wiki your example appears as non sargable. So as you know, you cannot take advantage of indexes